# Star Wars Trooper chooseable path book

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, choose-your-own-adventure

There was this Star Wars book I used to read back in middle school. It was about you being a trooper, and you got to decide what you did - i.e. commander, demolitions, etc. There were multiple endings. That's all I really remember of it. If any of you know, please let me know.

Comment: If you read this within the last ten years, it's probably one of these "Decide Your Destiny" books? http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars:_Decide_Your_Destiny

Comment: Can you inform us of when you were in middle school? There are a large amount of these books and a decade or a range of years would greatly help narrow down the scope.

Comment: A Stormtrooper training manual? I'm sorry I _missed_ out on that...

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[The Lost Legion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6508151-the-lost-legion)*, one of the books in the series *Star Wars: the Clone Wars Decide Your Destiny*?

The blurb for it reads:

> Do you have what it takes to be a clone trooper in the Republic Army? In this *Decide Your Destiny* story you can choose from multiple characters, such as medic, commander or demolitions expert, and dozens of paths to create your own adventure. With over twenty-five different endings, every time you read the book it'll be a whole new adventure.

[image: front cover of _The Lost Legion_]

If it's not this one, it might be one of [the others in the series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/46294-star-wars-the-clone-wars-decide-your-destiny).